# ruby on rails how to get html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to use this function to reload a table in my page:

```
function RefreshTable() {
   $( "#mytable" ).load( "my-page.html #mytable" );
}
```

but i dont know hot to get my-page correctly, this is my url in browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/ventas
```

this is my views directory

MyApp/app/views/ventas/index.html.erb

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$('#mytabl').html("<%= j (render partial: 'folder/my-page' ) %>");
```

Comment: So you can just make an ajax call and handle it in controller